# The way Java handles of arguments of type class

Tags: java, parameter-passing

I am looking at example in the example in Walter Savitch book "Java Introduction"

```
// This method does not do what we want it to do.
public static void openFile(String fileName,
    PrintWriter stream) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    stream = new PrintWriter(fileName);
}

PrintWriter toFile = null;
try
{
    openFile("data.txt", toFile);
}
```

Author gives explanation, which does not make any sense, as to why `toFile = null` after `try`

Thanks !

Comment: Can you show more code?  You can't have a _try_ without a _catch_ or _finally_.

Comment: What is the author's explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read that section of the book more deeply.  (I'm sure that it actually DOES make sense ... but you just haven't understood it yet.)

It is clear that the author is actually trying to illustrate an very important aspect of Java ... how parameters are passed.

Specifically, he is trying to illustrate that the two `stream` identifiers are for *different* variables, and that the assignment inside the method

```
stream = new PrintWriter(fileName);
```

does NOT effect the `stream` variable declared just before the `try`.  The value that is assigned to the `stream` variable inside the method gets lost.

This illustrates that Java uses "pass by value" as its parameter passing mechanism.  (If you need to get a value back from a method call, the simple way to do it is to `return` it.)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for response! I am a more knowledgeable in C/C++, and probably missed simple fact that parameters in Java are "passed by value" rather than "by reference". Thank for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

The author is trying to explain to you that changing what a variable refers to inside a method isn't visible outside the method.

`toFile` will be `null` after the call to `openFile()` because the reference value is passed to the method and assigned to the local `stream` variable. Changing the value of `stream` inside the method can't be seen outside the method unless you explicitly return it.

`openFile()` would need to return the new `PrintWriter`:

```
public static PrintWriter openFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    PrintWriter stream = new PrintWriter(fileName);
    return stream;
}
```

and be called as:

```
PrintWriter toFile = null;
try
{
    toFile = openFile("data.txt");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification about `return`